# Convergence of improper integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\arctan ^\alpha x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have to analyse the convergence of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\arctan ^\alpha x} dx$, $\alpha \in R$

I have written:
$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{c}\frac{1}{\arctan ^\alpha x} dx+\int_{c}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\arctan ^\alpha x} dx $

The first integral converges for $0<\alpha<1$

But I don't know how I can conclude something about the second integral.. the only thing that I know is that for $x \to \infty, \arctan x \to \pi/2$...

Comment: Second integral converges when $\alpha \gt 1$, so no dice.

Comment: @RonGordon Thanks for your comment. Please, see my comment to John Molokach's answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since as $x \to \infty$, $\arctan{x} \to \pi/2$, for a given $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n$ such that for every $x>n$, $\pi/2>\arctan{x}>\pi/2-\varepsilon$. Hence
$$ \int_n^{\infty} (\arctan{x})^{-\alpha} \, dx > \int_n^{\infty} (\pi/2-\varepsilon)^{-\alpha} \, dx = \infty $$
if $\alpha>0$, and
$$\int_n^{\infty} (\arctan{x})^{-\alpha} \, dx>\int_n^{\infty} (\pi/2)^{-\alpha} \, dx = \infty$$
if $\alpha<0$, so either way the integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Carrying on from your ending statement, that means that $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\arctan^\alpha x}\ge\frac{1}{(\pi/2)^\alpha},$ so I am assuming your integral diverges for $\alpha>1$ by comparison.

Comment: Please, tell me if I'm wrong: for $\alpha>0$ and x->$+\infty$, $1/x^{\alpha}<1/\arctan^{\alpha}$. $\int_{c}^{+\infty} 1/x^{\alpha}$ diverges for $\alpha<1$ . So The initial integral diverges. But why I can say that the second integral converges for $\alpha>1$? The only thing that the comparison test allows me to say isn't that the second integral diverges for $\alpha<1$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but isn't $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\arctan^\alpha x}\geq\frac{1}{(\pi/2)^\alpha}$?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I've corrected the answer.